# How to click a download button with R?

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to download data from a webpage (https://www.portaldaindustria.com.br/estatisticas/indicadores-industriais/) in R, which requires button-clicking to accomplish that.

Basically, I just need to click in the `Download` button next to "Série Recente".

I tried to get the url from the xlsx file and use `download.file()`, but it changes every month.

```
library(httr)

res <- POST("https://www.portaldaindustria.com.br/estatisticas/indicadores-industriais/",
            body = list(`DOWNLOAD` = ""),
            encode = "form",
            write_disk("Ind.xlsx"))
```

When I try this it returns an empty Excel file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply parse the source page and gather the required url dynamically? You can use an attribute = value css selector for this. You target the href by it containing the substring `serie-recente`. You can then pass that url to `download.file()`.

---

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.portaldaindustria.com.br/estatisticas/indicadores-industriais/"

download_folder <- "<your_download_folder_path>/"

download_link <- read_html(url) |>
  html_element("[href*=serie-recente]") |>
  html_attr("href")

download.file(download_link, 
              paste0(download_folder, gsub('.*/', '', download_link))
              , mode = "wb")
```